# Set the text selection color with jQuery. Demo not working

Tags: jquery, css, colors, selection, textselection

http://jsfiddle.net/uKdPM/

I've set the `::selection` color in css, so when you highlight the text on the screen, the color of the text is pink. I'm trying to now override that color through jQuery when the page loads. Seems like it should be super simple. But it's not working for me.

Comment: It wont happen because jquery cannot find p::selection, you could catch the p itself, but im unsure how to actually apply styling to pseudostuff like that

Comment: Not really related to the question, but I believe `::selection` was removed from the CSS3 spec, so use it with care.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change text selection highlight with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427981/change-text-selection-highlight-with-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe if you want to achieve this kind of effect, you need to apply the color change based on a CSS class. I forked your jsfiddle, and [heres the result](http://jsfiddle.net/duhTB/)

Although i think your question is interesting, im having a difficult time figuring where this can be put to practical use. Do you want to change the theme on the fly?

Comment: My use case: I was considering having a different color accent for each individual "article" on the website i'm building. They would be more like books than articles, much longer, so I was considering the possibility. I'm still not sure if it's something I wanna do.

Comment: I would not recommend you to it, honestly i think its a cheesy effect that easily can get quite annoying.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427981/change-text-selection-highlight-with-js) you can't change the highlight color of a selection, because there isn't a DOM interface for manipulating pseudo classes. What you could do is to change the class of the element.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I stumbled upon this question. The solution can be just adding a `<style>` tag with css properties into the document body.

`$('<style>
    p::selection{
                  background-color:#000;
                }
    p::-moz-selection{
                  background-color:#000;
    }</style>').insertAfter('body *:last');`

This might not be the most elegant way to do it, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

`::selection` is a **CSS** pseudo-class, not a jquery selector !

You can't do this `$('p::selection').css({color: "#3c3"})` and expect the text selection color to be changed.

---

- `$(<selector>)` allows you to **select** dom elements in flexible way, using IDs, css classes, attributes...
- `:hover`, `:after`... `::selection` are CSS-pseudo selector which allows you to **style** elements.

Even though the syntax of a jquery selector can look the same as a pseudo-class css, they are different.

---

By the way, it is not possible to change programmatically the style of css pseudo-classes (like `:hover`...).

Comment: Actually, you CAN do that AND expect the text selection color to be changed... it wont work, but I certainly did it, and expected it... just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you can [change to using classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473676/set-the-text-selection-color-with-jquery-demo-not-working/8473774#8473774) instead of directly setting the colour from JavaScript, then do that because it's much simpler.

Otherwise, see this question: [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Using the library provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077782/405015):

```
jss('p::selection', {
    color: '#3c3'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/uKdPM/9/