# Manipulate ::selection with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just wanted to do so on function

```
function changeGenre(toWhat) {
    [...]
    $('::selection').css("background-color",'rgb('+color+')');
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Why?

EDIT: `::selection` isn't a DOM element, so I'm looking for alternative way of solving this.

Comment: where is `color` variable decalred ? where is your html ? where and how you call `changeGenre` ?

Comment: I used `[...]` to not show you a whole function for no reason. Color is declared and is used many times in my code and it works. For example, in same function, I've got `$('.cover').css("background-color","rgb("+color+")");` and it works. Also, the `changeGenre` is called on button click, which has `onclick` attribute @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using it with css class:see this post:[Set the text selection color with jQuery. Demo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473676/set-the-text-selection-color-with-jquery-demo-not-working)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 changeGenre();
});

function changeGenre() {
    $('p').addClass("gr");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
p.gr::selection {
    background:#ff0099;
}
</style>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> ::selection is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>
```